# Parsing onesignal API response

Tags: php, onesignal

I want to parse the response from onesignal API using PHP. The following is the structure of the API response. I want to print the only certain parameters. How can I do that?

```
{
    "adm_big_picture": "",
    "adm_group": "",
    "adm_group_message": {
        "en": ""
    },
    "adm_large_icon": "",
    "adm_small_icon": "",
    "adm_sound": "",
    "spoken_text": {},
    "alexa_ssml": null,
    "alexa_display_title": null,
    "amazon_background_data": false,
    "android_accent_color": "FF9900FF",
    "android_group": "group key",
    "android_group_message": {
        "en": "group message for Android 6.0 and older"
    },
    "android_led_color": null,
    "android_sound": null,
    "android_visibility": 1,
    "app_id": "3beb3078-e0f1-4629-af17-fde833b9f716",
    "big_picture": "https://img.onesignal.com/n/37326fcc-2baa-45da-891c-ca9454a64957.png",
    "buttons": null,
    "canceled": false,
    "chrome_big_picture": "",
    "chrome_icon": "",
    "chrome_web_icon": "https://picture-resource.com/icon-image.png",
    "chrome_web_image": "https://picture-resource.com/image.png",
    "chrome_web_badge": "https://picture-resource.com/badge.png",
    "content_available": false,
    "contents": {
        "en": "English Message"
    },
    "converted": 1,
    "data": {
        "additional": "data",
        "campaign": "25"
    },
    "delayed_option": "immediate",
    "delivery_time_of_day": "2:32PM",
    "errored": 4,
    "excluded_segments": [],
    "failed": 0,
    "firefox_icon": "https://picture-resource.com/firefox_icon.png",
    "global_image": "https://link-to-your-image.com/image-resource-file.png",
    "headings": {
        "en": "English Message Title "
    },
    "id": "fd1723c6-bfaf-4f53-b4f4-0408ff43e18a",
    "include_player_ids": null,
    "include_external_user_ids": null,
    "included_segments": [
        "Subscribed Users"
    ],
    "thread_id": null,
    "ios_badgeCount": 1,
    "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
    "ios_category": "",
    "ios_sound": "explosion.wav",
    "apns_alert": {},
    "isAdm": false,
    "isAndroid": true,
    "isChrome": false,
    "isChromeWeb": true,
    "isAlexa": false,
    "isFirefox": true,
    "isIos": true,
    "isSafari": true,
    "isWP": false,
    "isWP_WNS": false,
    "isEdge": true,
    "large_icon": "https://img.onesignal.com/n/b5cadcf0-1297-4489-b865-545b421d8c5d.png",
    "priority": 5,
    "queued_at": 1580510246,
    "remaining": 0,
    "send_after": 1580510246,
    "completed_at": 1580510247,
    "small_icon": "small_icon",
    "successful": 232,
    "received": 5,
    "tags": null,
    "filters": null,
    "template_id": null,
    "ttl": 777,
    "url": "https://onesignal.com/blog",
    "web_url": null,
    "app_url": null,
    "web_buttons": null,
    "web_push_topic": null,
    "wp_sound": "",
    "wp_wns_sound": "",
    "platform_delivery_stats": {
        "edge_web_push": {
            "successful": 2,
            "failed": 0,
            "errored": 0
        },
        "chrome_web_push": {
            "successful": 26,
            "failed": 0,
            "errored": 0
        },
        "firefox_web_push": {
            "successful": 1,
            "failed": 0,
            "errored": 0
        },
        "android": {
            "successful": 198,
            "errored": 1,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "safari_web_push": {
            "successful": 3,
            "failed": 0,
            "errored": 0
        },
        "ios": {
            "successful": 2,
            "errored": 3,
            "failed": 0
        }
    },
    "ios_attachments": {
        "id": "https://img.onesignal.com/n/23f60ba6-8f2e-4ce1-bdf5-86e6286c2e39.png"
    }
}
```

I used the PHP code given by them but no luck

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/c3971bca-b49f- 47c8-b9a0-ace613a06431?app_id=MYAPPID");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                           'Authorization: Basic AUTHKEY'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
        $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    $return = json_encode( $return);

      print("\n\nJSON received:\n");


      $yummy = json_decode($return, true);
      print_r($yummy);
      echo("<br>");
      echo "checking---".$yummy[0]['app_id']; // I donnot know to to access this
      print("\n");
```

I want to print only certain parameters so that I can do further processing. But I am unable to parse the response.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Please note that insisting on writing errors is not a good strategy to attracting answers here. Moreover, writing quality questions is important, as we hope they will be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is an object, not an array, so (once you've decoded it) you can access its properties directly. Just ditch the `[0]` and there's no problem.

```
echo "checking---".$yummy['app_id'];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QKUQN.

The `[0]` would make sense if the JSON was an array and your data was inside the first element of that array. But for a simple object, there's no extra layer like that to traverse.